# Accessing the Device Camera with getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

Below codes was successfully working until i have added some additional codes because i am trying to make aware of users that their camera ready / available or not.My html looks like:

```
<div id="notes">
</div>
<div id="video-container">
<video id="camera-stream" width="500" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

And here the .js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var statusHTML = '<ul>';
  navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: true
    },
    function(localMediaStream) {
statusHTML += '<li>You have a camera!</li>';
var vid = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
vid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
    },
    function(err) {
  statusHTML += '<li>You dont have a camera!</li>';
      console.log('The following error occurred when trying to use getUserMedia: ' + err);
    }
  );
  statusHTML += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = statusHTML;
} else {
  alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
}
}
</script>
```

I have added this 4 codes which does not work and i am not sure if i am doing right:

```
  var statusHTML = '<ul>';
  statusHTML += '<li>You have a camera!</li>';
  statusHTML += '<li>You dont have a camera!</li>';
  statusHTML += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = statusHTML;
```

All in all I am trying to print a message to the page that ass soon as user load the page It should says they have available camera or not. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the innerHTML directly and not after the function with a variable. I tried it and it worked fine:

```
window.onload = function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(
        {
          video: true,
          audio: true
        },
        function(localMediaStream) {
          document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = '<ul><li>You have a camera!</li></ul>';
          var vid = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
          vid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
        },
        function(err) {
          document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = '<ul><li>You dont have a camera!</li></ul>';
          alert('The following error occurred when trying to use getUserMedia: ' + err);
        }
        );
    } else {
      alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your time. This is very close to what am I looking for. Do you think is it possible to show message before notification (site that wants to use your microphone and camera).

Comment: You mean you want to alert thie message: 'site that wants to use your microphone and camera' before everything else?

Comment: Simply, in the onload function, in the first line, add `alert('site that wants to use your microphone and camera');`